# Using SVN Checkout from terminal on MAC OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, svn

I apologize for the newbie question.  When using svn checkout on a repository, that only copies the directories locally to my machine correct?  I want to make sure I do not remove anything from the repository.

Comment: [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) - aka the SVN book - will provide a lot of useful information about using SVN. It's free, too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

That's right, doing an svn checkout operation does not change anything on the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

Yes 'svn checkout' just download source code from repository to your pc. It doesn't modify any of respository. 'svn update' too.

But, 'svn commit' will change your repository.